# searchkick - Must specify fields to search

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Учу RoR. Добавляю на сайт поле поиска (в моем случае поиска фильмов). Поиск делаю с помощью гема searchkick. Но при попытке поиска выдает мне такую ошибку Must specify fields to search.
Что сделал я:

1. Установил Elasticsearch, проверил. Все работает, если сделать запрос на 9200 порт, то выдает:

`name   "95uHTn_"
cluster_name    "elasticsearch"
cluster_uuid    "pIiQyXbfRouPMmL7oNUxMA"
version 
number  "6.1.3"
build_hash  "af51318"
build_date  "2018-01-26T18:22:55.523Z"
build_snapshot  false
lucene_version  "7.1.0"
minimum_wire_compatibility_version  "5.6.0"
minimum_index_compatibility_version "5.0.0"
tagline "You Know, for Search"`

Elasticsearch - работает.

2. Установил гем searchkick 2.4
3. В модель Movie добавил

`class Movie < ApplicationRecord
    searchkick
end`

4. Роуты

`Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :movies do
    collection do
        get 'search'
    end 
    resources :reviews, except: [:show, :index]
  end
  root 'movies#index' 
end`

5. На форму

`<%= form_tag search_movies_path, method: :get, class: "navbar-form navbar-right", role: "search" do %>
        <p>
          <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "form-control" %>
          <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn btn-default" %>
        </p>
      <% end %>`

6. И в контроллер Movie

`def search
    if params[:search].present?
      @movies = Movie.search(params[:search])
    else
      @movies = Movie.all
    end
  end`

7. Проиндексировал таблицы поиска сначала так

`rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Movie`

потом

`rake searchkick:reindex:all`

В теории все должно работать. Но ошибка Must specify fields to search все равно в контроллере на строчке

`@movies = Movie.search(params[:search])`

Проверил с помощью byebug. В параметры поиска передается значение с формы поиска. Не могу понять в чем причина. 
Вот с отладчика

`@_params = <ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"Accident Man", "controller"=>"movies", "action"=>"search"} permitted: false>`

Смущает только вот `permitted: false`. Но никаких ограничений доступа я не ставил!

Comment: Ограничение стоит по умолчанию. Никогда не видели записи `params.require(сущность).permit(поля)`? А ответ на ваш вопрос, с виду, есть аж [в **Getting Started**](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#getting-started).

Comment: Видел.  Уже несколько раз пролистал Getting Started но в упор не вижу ((

Comment: `products = Product.search("apples", fields: [:name])`?

Comment: Увидел)) Спасибо! `@movies = Movie.search(params[:search], fields: [:title])` и все работает!!!

Comment: Напишите ответ тогда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно было указать поля, по которым искать!

```
@movies = Movie.search(params[:search], fields: [:title])
```